# ubuntu 20.04 system hangs when starting monitor mode

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, freeze, network-monitoring

I tried putting ubuntu 20.04 system in monitor mode using airmon and iwconfig, but in both ways my computer is getting hanged(wifi-RTL8723DE). How to solve this problem ?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 I can guess from the flag you mean 20.04?

Comment: @David updated !